# Curve fitting using Scipy leads to unexpected result

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a data set which I can fit to a given function. I did it using Desmos graphing calculator and got the expected results. But when I implement it using Matplotlib, I get a totally different curve and I can't figure out the error in my code. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')


def func(x, a, b):
    return a/(np.sin((x-b)/2))**4

x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', label="Observed data points")


plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")


plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here is the expected plot (plotted using Desmos): [image]

And here is what I got from Matplotlib: [image]

Any help would be appreciated. This is the `data.txt` for reference:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| -0.523598776 | 0.530580093 |
| -0.436332313 | 1.016423844 |
| -0.34906585 | 6.38245854 |
| -0.261799388 | 18.70139225 |
| -0.174532925 | 30.7389007 |
| 0.174532925 | 13.59465343 |
| 0.261799388 | 4.011313119 |
| 0.34906585 | 0.805865977 |
| 0.436332313 | 0.50894953 |
| 0.523598776 | 0.253654518 |

Comment: You need to provide a minimal reproducible example. We need the txt file with the data.

Comment: I added the ```data.txt```

Comment: You may need to provide a reasonable initial guess (`p0`). If the default guess is very fast off, it will not converge. Unlike the `scipy` `least_squares` method, `curve_fit` provides little feedback on the fit success.

Answer (score 0):

You have a singularity at `x==b` (your function tends to infinity). That makes it very difficult for `curve_fit` to find a value of `b` that "crosses" any of your data points. Since your data is about zero centered, you'll have better luck providing a an initial value such as

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, [0.0, 0.0])
```